# Are all the functions whose fourier weight is concentrated on the small sized sets computed by AC0 circuits?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

Are all the functions whose fourier weight is concentrated on the small sized sets(or terms with low degree) computed by $\mathsf{AC}^0$ circuits ?

Comment: This question sounds interesting, though I lack some of the background in fourier analysis. I would appreciate references to related literature.

Comment: @Markus: this book 2.0 by Ryan O'Donnell is an excellent reference: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/

Comment: almost the converse to [Linial, Mansour, Nissan 1993](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=174138)? aaronsons result, [counterexample to generalized Linial-Nissan](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/glnfalse.pdf) seems close? but imho theres got to be a way to generalize the 1993 result somehow... maybe in a big way....

Comment: another similar idea instead of AC^0, harder to disprove, would be depth unlimited but total gate limited circuits bounded by some "small" function say polynomial etc...? also afaik the relation between monotone circuits and fourier coefficients is not so well known...?

Comment: see also [polylogarithmic independence fools AC^0 circuits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.7081) by braverman

Comment: @vzn Thanks for the additional resource suggestions.

Comment: further thought it seems to be related to the complexity of computing the parity fn of subsets of input variables. see ch2 of juknas book, _boolean fn complexity, advances and frontiers_

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Consider the following function on $\{0,1\}^n$:
$$ f(x) = x_0 \land \cdots \land x_{n-\sqrt{n}-1} \land (x_{n-\sqrt{n}} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{n-1}). $$
Clearly this function is hard for AC<sup>0</sup>. On the other hand, the function is almost constant, so almost all of its Fourier spectrum is on the first level.

If you want a balanced counterexample, consider
$$ g(x) = x_0 \oplus \left[x_1 \land \cdots \land x_{n-\sqrt{n}-1} \land (x_{n-\sqrt{n}} \oplus 
\cdots \oplus x_{n-1})\right]. $$
This function is almost always equal to $x_0$, so almost all of its Fourier spectrum is on the first two levels.

Comment: Do you have any robust examples where the function can't be approximated in AC0?

Comment: A function concentrated on the first $O(1)$ levels is always close to a function depending on $O(1)$ inputs, so if we're interested in only $O(1)$ levels, then there are no robust examples.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What does Fourier spectrum level mean? Why is this function hard for $AC^0$?

Comment: @Arul A Fourier level consists of all Fourier coefficients corresponding to sets of a given size. We think of them as ordered in increasing order of size. As for why this function is hard for AC0, this is an exercise. Hint: parity is hard for AC0.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to understand the question according to the precise meaning of "small size" and "concentrate."

1) If you consider Boolean functions so that $1-o(1)$ of their l-2 norm is concentrated on small sized $S$ then the answer is no - the majority function is an example such that $1-o(1)$ of the l-2 norm is on bounded sets and is not in ${\rm AC^0}$.

2) There is a theorem of Bourgain that if the concentration is well above that of the majority function then the function is approximately a Junta, and thus depends on O(1) variables.

3) You can ask that the total influence which is expectation of |S| with respect to the distribution described by $\hat f^2(S)$ is small. For functions in $AC^0$ the total influence is at most ${\rm polylog} (n)$. If the total influence is O(1) then the function is close to a Junta, namely depending on O(1) variables.

4) If the total influence is $O(\log n)$ it is possible but not known that the function is close to a function in $AC^0$.

5) If the total influence is $O(polylog (n))$ then another possibility is a function of bounded depth and $n^{polylog (n)}$ size. It is possible, but unknown, that every function of total influence polylog (n) is close to such a function.